# Securing session cookies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I used Pullreview to review my app. It came up with this security notice:

> Be secure using session cookies

on this line:
Myapp::Application.config.secret_key_base = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'

The how to fix segment suggests that I should modify it to something similar to this:

```
cookies['user_name'] = { value: 'david', httponly: true }
```

I tried adding curly brackets but it returns an error.

So, how do I assign the "httponly: true" value to "Myapp::Application.config.secret_key_base" then?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you get the error. I use signed cookies for added security, like so:

```
cookies.signed[:foobar] = {
  value: {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'baz'
  },
  expires: 2.weeks.from_now,
  httponly: true
}
```